# ADMIN$ and other shares not working remotely on XP machines

Tags: windows-server-2003, firewall, windows-xp, migration, admt

I'm trying to use ADMT to migrate several XP machines to a new domain and the utility (nor command line) is able to access the admin$ share or any drive share.

I've added the required registry key (HKCurrent\Services\LanMan\Param) for both servers and workstation admin sharing, rebooted the PC and still am unable to access it.

How can I access the admin share on these PCs?

If it helps, this machine used to have McAfee installed, and the Windows firewall enabled.  I stoppped both of them and the machine is still not allowing me to access it remotely by a drive$ share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First,** as silly as it might sound, consider running an offline virus scan using a boot CD such as Kaspersky's rescue CD. Any time administrative shares go missing, especially when the proper registry keys exist, my radar is immediately tweaked for some kind of malicious software. It can't hurt to pop a CD in and let it sit, crunching away for a few minutes or hours.

**Second,** go into your adapter's properties and make sure that "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" is enabled.

**Third,** let the flailing begin! You can reset your TCP/IP stack which sometimes clears up weirdness like this. As administrator, run `netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt` to reset the TCP/IP stack. Next reset winsock2 with `netsh int reset` or just reset the catalog with `netsh winsock reset catalog`. I will leave a thorough investigation of what those things to as an exercise for the reader.

**Fourth,** if you don't have the time to spend tracking down the root cause, consider an XP repair install. Note that you will need to reapply updates after the repair install. Existing files are kept in tact, however a backup before this is performed can't hurt.

Comment: File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks was disabled!!! Who the heck would disable that!?

Comment: @makerofthings7 You know who would do that? I know who would do that. Bad people would do that. Or, maybe 1) Those who have a fanatical desire for security and think *"Disable* ***ALL*** *the things!"*, or 2) Someone who disables things they don't understand.

Comment: Meh, it was probably a bad person. =)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the registry key to the **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`** (HKLM) hive instead of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.
2. Make sure the **`Server`** service is started. Try to restart it if it is already running.
3. To make sure Windows Firewall is not blocking anything, enable logging of dropped packets and try to access the shares again. Examine the firewall log to see if anything gets dropped.
   (Run -> firewall.cpl -> Advanced -> Security Logging -> Settings -> Log dropped packets)

If the **ADMIN$** share exists but is still unavailable, try removing it and reboot (this should recreate it).